# How to add existing project to Visual studio 2012 after renaming the project path

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I had a C# class library project as part of my solution. I later updated the root folder of the project. Since the solution was pointing to the wrong path, I had to "delete" the project and then re-add it.
However, when I add the existing project, it says "The project file \myproject.csproj' has been moved, renamed or is not on your computer".

This is baffling because the .sln file has no reference to the project. (I checked the text contents)
How does VS cache the project with it's old folder path? The solution is version controlled in TFS, but the mappings point to the new folder structure, so it's even more confusing as to where it's trying to get the old folder path from.

Edit: I checked the .csproj file, the .csproj.vspscc and none of them have a path variable in them.
I have also tried deleting the .suo file.

Comment: Try to delete the *hidden* .suo file in the root folder.

Comment: I've stumbled on this before. VS doesn't seem to have a proper renaming function, therefore I usually end up creating a new solution with the right name, and then add all the source files to it. They should fix it though, it would make life so much easier...

Comment: Can you explain how TFS relates into this? is your project under source control, is the solution? did you rename the project through TFS or did you do it on the local file system. Why did you Delete the project rather than REMOVE it in the solution? is the SLN file being checked out when you Remove and add the project?

Comment: @Just TFS - I just wanted to mention TFS for completeness' sake although it likely doesn't cause the issue. By delete of project, I meant that I "removed" the project reference from the solution, not physically delete the project. Also, both my project and solution were under version control. I renamed the project via file system and then mapped the binding to TFS successfully.

Comment: @PatriceGahide - I tried that a while back as well. I did it again and it now works. If you add your comment as an answer I will close the question.

Comment: I renamed the project via file system and then mapped the binding to TFS successfully.               I would recommend doing this through TFS in Future as it may help you to avoid the issues you have seen

Answer (score 52, accepted):

This has been a trouble with Visual Studio for years now. In such a case, deleting the hidden .suo file in the root folder and restart VS will reconstruct a proper .suo file and almost always eliminate the issue.

If you use TFS, take a look at Just TFS' comment in the original post to avoid this problem in the future.

Comment: In VS2015, my troublesome file was `./.vs/[Project Name]/v14/.suo`.

Comment: VS2015 problem file for me was [Solution Folder]/.vs/[Solution Name]/v14/.suo

Comment: Just bumped into the same problem in 2017. Will convert repository to git real soon now...